# In Vue.js, how to disable caching of computed properties?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

> Before 0.12.8, computed properties behave just like getters - every time you access it, the getter function is re-evaluated. In 0.12.8 this has been improved - computed properties are cached and lazily re-evaluated only when necessary.

For my current project, I actually need some properties to be re-evaluated on every access. The reason the current lazy evaluation isn't working is because in some of my properties there are other "dynamic variables" that are not under Vue.js's watch.

Comment: Use a pre 0.12.8 version?

Answer (score 38):

According to the docs, you can simply set cache to false:

```
computed: {
  example: {
    cache: false,
    get: function () {
      return Date.now() + this.msg
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not just create example() in `methods` for this case?
As I understand using computed with cache = false have sense when setter for computed exists also. In other cases method should be used, isn't it?

Answer (score 6):

You can use way from @Xethron but using the short syntax of functions:

```
computed: {
  example: {
    cache: false,
    get () {
      return Date.now() + this.msg
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[According to the official docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#cache-false-deprecated), although the earlier answers from @Xethron and @Илья Зеленько were correct up to Vue 1.x, they have been deprecated since then in favour of a method-based approach.

So the above examples would change from this:

```
computed: {
  example: {
    cache: false,
    get () {
      return Date.now() + this.msg
    }
  }
}
```

...to this:

```
methods: {
  getExample () {
    return Date.now() + this.msg
  }
}
```

**N.B note that we would now access the value in the template by calling the function**, so this:

`<p>message: {{ example }}</p>`

...needs to be this:

`<p>message: {{ getExample() }}</p>`